# How to connect Blueprints to a remote neo4j server

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop-blueprint, anormcypher

I am trying to merge two separate efforts. I have an application that currently uses `anormcypher` to talk to a remote `neo4j` database, and I am now developing an application that uses `TinkerPop Blueprints`.

In Blueprints I can create a new embedded `Neo4jGraph` but I don't know how to connect it to my remote neo4j (community edition, not HA) server. I'm looking for the documentation that tells me how to configure that `connection (host::port)`.

Comment: Blueprints are now deprecated with tinkerpop 3. You can  connect by using the bolt protocol, see my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180335/5973334