# How to connect Gremlin Server to a remote Neo4j Database?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I have a Question about the Gremlin Server. Is it possible to connect a Gremlin Server to a Neo4j Server (remote database)? At the Moment I have a Neo4j database in my fileysystem and a Gremlin Server which connect to it. Now I want both Servers running with the same Neo4J Database

I use:
Gremlin Server 3.1.1
Neo4J Community 2.2.8 (can update to 2.3.2)

I've found another Question but without answers [How to connect Blueprints to a remote neo4j server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405929/how-to-connect-blueprints-to-a-remote-neo4j-server)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  [SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt) that provides a connection over the bolt protocol.
When starting the connection, you can [provide a remote address](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt#connecting-to-the-database)

Note that the functionalities are, at the moment, limited [with indexes](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt/issues/46).

---

### Background on the "other" Neo4j Java plugin

When dealing with Gremlin/Tinkerpop,  the current implementation is [a wrapper of the Neo4j Java API](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#neo4j-gremlin), although it can parse some cypher queries, it doesn't send them to the server.
Also, it doesn't convert the gremlin queries into cypher queries.

If you look a the file  [`conf/neo4j-empty.properties`](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-server/conf/neo4j-empty.properties) you will notice `gremlin.neo4j.directory=/tmp/neo4j`.  This is the path to the actual store, where your data is.
In simplified terms, there is no Neo4j server running, just java binaries that know how  to deal with the Neo4j store binaries.

> neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl is NOT Apache 2 licensed

Comment: I configured `gremlin.neo4j.directory=/tmp/neo4j` and it worked. However, when I change the directory to other path like `/Users/abc/xyz/neo4j` it does not work anymore. It gave me **gremlin-groovy is not an available Gremlin ScriptEngine**. Do you have any idea, please?

Comment: You should post a new question, with more details. Thanks